# Is it possible to have preloaded usb drivers for device

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, drivers, plug-and-play

I have a KMV switch on my desktop that I only use to switch keyboard and mouse from one pc to the next.

Whenever I press the button to switch computer the first computer plays the sound indicating that the usb has been unplugged and remove while the other pc waits a few moments and then registers the drivers of the device. (They are already installed but it takes a few seconds to activate the device on plug in. The process takes about 5 to 10 seconds each time. Is there a way to eliminate this time?

Knowing that the usb port isn't going to change ever. 
Meaning the KMV usb hub will always be on the same usb port on the PC.
The usb mouse will always be on the same position on the hub on the KMV switch.
and ditto for the keyboard.

Would it be possible, instead of having the computer query the port every time it is detectsed, that it would sort of have preloaded driver and just be primed and ready to accept instructions from that port? This way the moment a device is switched over there is no load time as it would already be primed and ready to go. Kind of preloading the driver if you will.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the USB device itself because Windows 7 already had the device drivers loaded.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you've got a PS/2 KVM with a USB port, and instead of using the PS/2 ports, you're trying to use the shared USB port?  If that's the case, you're not going to avoid the behavior you describe - that USB port is meant to toggle with the KVM.

Comment: @ernie I know the USB will toggle with the KVM, but can the machines themselves can be configured to ignore the toggle (I mean I know that the toggle cuts off the access of the device to the computer) but since the same device is going to be on that exact spot when the toggle returns, why re-initiate the drivers again? Can't the computer just keep the driver active and ignore it's inaccessibility. So instead of detecting when the usb mounts unmounts. Just pretend it's always mounted even if inaccessible. I don't know if I am being clear. (The KMV btw has no ps/2, it's ports are all usb)

Comment: @Ramhound There is no problem with the devices. I'm unclear what you mean. Switching with the KMV is equivalent of unplugging a usb device from one pc and plugging it into another except without the physical exertion of going under the desk to do the deed of unplugging and plugging. Instead I just press a button. It's a switch.